# mysql fulltext union words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a mysql fulltext question. Refrence on: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('(+apple +juice)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

This return 14 items

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('(+apple +pie)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

This return 36 items

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('(+apple +pie)|(+apple +juice)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

This return 1910 items, obviously, my query has problem. How to search words exactly contains `(+apple +pie)` and `(+apple +juice)`? I think it should be return `14+36=50items`

And in my purpose, I need a union search for

`(+apple +pie) (+apple +juice) (+apple +macintosh) (+apple +turnover) (+apple +strudel) (+pear +pie) (+pear +juice) (+pear +macintosh) (+pear +turnover) (+pear +strudel)`

it should be return nearly 520 items. Thanks.

Comment: use the union operator: query1 union query2 - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: @Adrian, this would be a long long query sentence. I have 10 search key words at last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('+apple +(pie juice)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

ETA: Missed the pear clauses my first read through. To get all the ones you listed I *think* this should work:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('+((apple +(pie juice macintosh turnover strudel)) (pear +(pie juice macintosh turnover strudel)))' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

That should translate into "must contain apple and one of pie, juice, macintosh, turnover, or strudel OR pear and one of pie, juice, macintosh, turnover, or strudel.

If that doesn't work I would do this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('+apple +(pie juice macintosh turnover strudel)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
UNION
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('+pear +(pie juice macintosh turnover strudel)' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

Comment: so how to deal the last my purpose search? `(SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('+apple (+pie +juice +macintosh +turnover +strudel)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) UNION (SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MATCH (aindex,bindex) AGAINST ('+pear (+pie +juice +macintosh +turnover +strudel)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))` ?

Comment: Added two possible solutions for that. Hopefully the first works.

Comment: great, thanks, also could be `(+(apple pear) +(pie juice macintosh turnover strudel))`  :)